# no sound after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: sound, 15.04, pulseaudio, soundcard

hello I tried the alsamixer in the terminal and the GUI both have volume all the way up and was unmuted and I had sound before but I had to upgrade case something happened and every one said an upgrade would fix the issue from before I use my computer to watch Netflix on my TV so M was trying to fix this issue quickly if I could I'm not sure of what to do could y'all help me with what I need to give y'all for info to help solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

What kind off connection do they have wired blue tooth, which kind off hardware? then there could be a chance to find some thing

Comment: its a desktop with it hooked into the mother board

Comment: qhich is the name off the hardware off it?

Comment: the sound cards are c-media electronics inc cmi8738 (rev 10) and subsystem: c-media electronics inc device 0111

Comment: mother board is gigabyte technology ltd ga-ep45-d55/ga-eg45m-d52h

Comment: intell corp 4 series chipset dram controller rev 3

Comment: http://www.cmedia.com.tw/productsdetail/page-p/c1serno-25/c2serno-28/pserno-31.html

Comment: this one is from linux http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/SND_CMIPCI.html

Comment: i hope you can find it out with these both links i posted to  your issue

Comment: how do i install it

Comment: download it and it should install it either with the linux version ubuntu or wine here is another that might help you out http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=902747

Comment: how to i install it which do i get

Comment: Which of them is it that you´d like to install?

Comment: the Linux one is the one id like to install

Comment: http://pciids.sourceforge.net/

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/213488/how-to-install-hardware-drivers-on-linux/

Comment: is where im at with the link for the linux one you sent me to

Comment: ok but where can i find the guide to install the drivers my self  i mean i dont even know what software im trying to install

Comment: ive already tried the additional software

Comment: ok if i install another sound card how do i know if it will work

Comment: if you want to install from linux you need to download it and install it if it doesn´t works you open the terminal && ctrl-alt-T && and give the command && $ sudo apt-get install .............

Comment: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/drivers

Comment: it says invalid operation for: sudo apt-get install pci.ids_0.1.tar.bz2

Comment: oh that one you need this to unpack with your file manager and extract it to install

Comment: sudo apt-get installpciids_0.1.tar.bz2
[sudo] password for axl: 
E: Invalid operation installpciids_0.1.tar.bz2
axl@AlienWare-EP45-UD3L:~$ sudo apt-get installpciids_0.1.tar.bz
E: Invalid operation installpciids_0.1.tar.bz
axl@AlienWare-EP45-UD3L:~$ sudo apt-get install pciids_0.1.tar.bz2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pciids_0.1.tar.bz2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'pciids_0.1.tar.bz2'

Comment: E: Unable to locate package pciids_0.1.tar.bz2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'pciids_0.1.tar.bz2'
axl@AlienWare-EP45-UD3L:~$ sudo apt-get install pci.ids.gz
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pci.ids.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'pci.ids.gz'
axl@AlienWare-EP45-UD3L:~$

Comment: gee am looking further

Comment: huh what are you saying gee am looking further

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/192246

Comment: Now you will have it i hope this will solve your issue

Comment: it says not solved

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/problems-with-audio-card-c-media-electronics-inc-cm8738-4175440597/

Comment: if these don´t work unplug reboot and plug in when it´s running and possibly better to uninstall the alsa

Comment: last thing you can do is install pavucontrol

Comment: its already installed still no luck

Comment: probably a broke wire connection off your plugged cable or a broke sound card

Answer (score 0):

After several days trying to learn how to fix this by reading all of your posts, testing all advice to no avail, the solution turned out to be hitting F10 during boot up and finding that  'integrated audio' was disabled.

Am new here and a novice so may still be missing something but damn glad to have sound back. Thanks for the education past few days.